# Every meromorphic function on $P^n$ is rational

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm reading the proof of "Every meromorphic function on $P^n$ is rational" in Griffiths&Harris. Consider the principal divisor $(\phi)$ and its zero-divisor $(\phi)_0$ and pole-divisor $(\phi)_{\infty}$. By Chow's theorem, $(\phi)_0$ and $(\phi)_{\infty}$ are zero locus of two homogeneous polynomials $F$ and $G$. To show $F$ and $G$ are of the same degree. The authors gave the reason that $(\phi)$ is homologous to zero since its Chern class is trivial. But I don't know how does this imply that $F$ and $G$ are of the same degree. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $H_{2n-2}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb P^n) = \mathbb Z \cdot [H]$, where $H$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$, and the degree of any hypersurface $Z \subset \mathbb P^n$ is exactly the number $k$ such that $[Z]  = k [H]$.
As $(\phi)$ is homologous to $0$, the hypersurface $(\phi)_0$ is homologous to $(\phi)_\infty$. So both define the same homology class in $H_{2n-2}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb P^n)$, hence they have the same degree, which is the degree of $F$ and $G$.

Comment: Maybe, is the homology $H_{2n-2}(\mathbb P^n, \mathbb Z)$, to clarify?

Comment: @Ayaka Yes, thanks for pointing that out! My first thoughts used Chow groups, and I mixed up the indices.